# ('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account') with oauth2client (Python)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-analytics, google-api

I'm trying to get Google Analytics data with this guide: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

```
def get_access_token(request):
    return {'access_t': ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEY_FILEPATH, SCOPE).get_access_token().access_token }
```

With the code above I'm trying to a create a function and return the access token to the context in my admin template.

However. I get this error I don't know what to do with:

```
('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account')
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: What value do you have **KEY_FILEPATH** set to? It sounds like you haven't installed your credentials correctly. Go to the Google developer console and set up a service account and download the credentials. Remember to change the view ID to the view you add the service account to.

Answer (score 30):

I too was running in to this. The fix in my case was to use the correct json file. I needed to use the one that was saved when I created the service account key, not the one with the service account client:

[image: developer console API key interface]

Hope that helps!

Comment: The instructions from the Google Analytics API v4 Quickstart guide are not up to date. Right now this is still the correct answer!

Comment: Livesaver. Thank you so much for this fix!

Comment: Check out this answer for a step by step guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49965912/2217801

Answer (score 1):

It seams like the sample in google-api-python-client has it right

[google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/analytics](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/analytics)