# Google Sheets api works only on my browser

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheets API and reading information from one of my Google Sheets on my website. I hosted my website and when other users launch the website they are not able to see info pulled from Google Sheets when I launch the website I am able to see the information. Why is Google Sheets API info getting pulled only for me and not globally?

So I tried opening the webpage in incognito mode and I'm still not able to see the info.

Comment: What error do you get in incognito mode? ["The caller does not have permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949318/google-sheets-api-returns-the-caller-does-not-have-permission-when-using-serve) ?

Comment: If you still haven't solved this, please find out what error you're getting from the API (e.g. test in incognito mode and look for the request in the developer tools network tab) and edit that into your question.

Comment: I got rid of oAuth and seems to be working fine on all browsers now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your app won't work for other users and for you in incognito mode because you're not authenticated with Google. You need to setup oauth2 as explained here:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Comment: I have an oAuth2 setup for me already I have a clientID, apiKey.