# still having Unhandled Exception: GSheetsException: The caller does not have permission

Tags: flutter, google-sheets-api

when trying to get ((final ss = await gsheets.spreadsheet(_spreadsheetId);)) this value while I did every thing related to *credentials still having Unhandled Exception: GSheetsException: The caller does not have permission
flutter doctor is OK
some one told me : you need to **give permission to access the spreadsheet to the service account**
which I think that is what I need to know how ^*^ ((thanks in advance))

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949318/google-sheets-api-returns-the-caller-does-not-have-permission-when-using-serve

Comment: it was putting my app email account as one of shared people who have an access to that sheet , but still a question please, any one knows in dart how could I make it by code not as in attached picture ^_^

Answer (score 0):

hello you must go to your worksheet in google sheets from drive and share the book in the file option and then share. You share it however you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).