# GET request - androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/ - throws 403 "The caller does not have permission"

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token

HttpGet request - using `HttpWebRequest`

```
https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/reviews
```

> Getting 403 forbidden exception - The caller does not have permission

Params -

- `{access_token}` - Generated `token` from Google OAuth
- `{packageName}` - 'com.facebook.orca'

Sample request - [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.facebook.orca/reviews?access_token={token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.facebook.orca/reviews?access_token=%7Btoken%7D)

Response -

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Reference - https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews/list

Stackoverflow -
[Google Sheets API returns "The caller does not have permission" when using server key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949318/google-sheets-api-returns-the-caller-does-not-have-permission-when-using-serve)

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem :/