# Google Cloud authorization keeps failing with Python 3 - Type is None, expected one of ('authorized_user', 'service_account')

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I am trying to download a file for the first time from Google Cloud Storage.

I set the path to the googstruct.json service account key file that I downloaded from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

Do need to set the authorization to Google Cloud outside the code somehow?  Or is there a better "How to use Google Cloud Storage" then the one on the google site?
It seems like I am passing the wrong type to the **storage_client = storage.Client()**
the exception string is below.

> Exception has occurred: google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError
> The file C:\Users\Cary\Documents\Programming\Python\QGIS\GoogleCloud\googstruct.json does not have a valid type.
> Type is None, expected one of ('authorized_user', 'service_account').

***MY PYTHON 3.7 CODE***

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:\\GoogleCloud\\googstruct.json"

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'structure_ssi'
destination_file_name = "C:\\Users\\18809_PIPEM.shp"
source_blob_name = '18809_PIPEM.shp'
download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name)

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

I did look at this but I cannot tell if this is my issue.   I have tried both.

[('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account') with oauth2client (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709324/unexpected-credentials-type-none-expected-service-account-with-oauth2/41494815)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error means that the Json Service Account Credentials that you are trying to use `C:\\GoogleCloud\\googstruct.json` are corrupt or the wrong type.

The first (or second) line in the file `googstruct.json` should be `"type": "service_account"`.

Another few items to improve your code:

1. You do not need to use `\\`, just use `/` to make your code easier
   and cleaner to read.
2. Load your credentials directly and do not modify environment
   variables:

`storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('C:/GoogleCloud/googstruct.json')`

3. Wrap API calls in try / except. Stack traces do not impress customers. It is better to have clear, simple, easy to read error messages.

Comment: Yes - That is correct. :)  Thanks.   I deleted that one and created a new one.